# Send email from Access if DOB is within 'n' days

Tags: ms-access, vba

I needed to make it in access so that I send an email to a certain customer when their date of birth is within 3 days.

```
Dim rs as dao.recordset
set rs = currentdb.openrecordset(“DiscountEmail”)
with rs
    if .eof and .bof then (No Records found for this query.)
        Msgbox “ No emails will be sent because there are no records from the query ‘DiscountEmail’ “
    else
        do until .eof 

            DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , ![Email Address Field], , , “Happy Birthday!”, “Hello ” & ![First Name Field] & _
                    “, ” & Chr(10) & “Come in on your birthday and receive a 10% discount!”, False

            .edit
            ![Email_Sent_Date] = now()
            .update
            .movenext 
        loop

    End If
end with

If Not rs Is Nothing Then
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End If
```

I have this code, but now I just need to make it so that if a certain customer's birthday (In my table 'CustomerInfo') is within 3 days, it sends them an email saying that they can come in on their birthday and receive a discount.

Also, I want to make it so that this happens automatically (so I don't have to press any button), but so that it sends it only once, and so I can send it again next year.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have some event in order to fire this event. An Access database is just a file, so when you're not using it, it's not running any code.

Doing a simple check every time the database is opened, maybe on the first form's On Load event would be the way to go. I assume your `DiscountEmail` RecordSet is the one querying for emails within the 3 day period.

Your solution is to either put this in the onLoad event for your first form or to use another service. As far as not spamming the emailee more than once, just add a `emailSent` field or log sent emails to a different table, and handle  it after the email is sent.

Example query to find the relevant emails:

```
Select email from Users Where dateOfBirth between dateAdd("d",-3,Date()) AND dateAdd("d",3,Date());
```

Do send an email, you could use SMTP and CDO. Create an email function called something like `sendEmail`

```
 Public Sub SendEmail(strTo as STring, strFrom as String, strSubj as String, strBody as String)
Dim imsg As Object
Dim iconf As Object
Dim flds As Object
Dim schema As String

Set imsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iconf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set flds = iconf.Fields

' send one copy with SMTP server (with autentication)
schema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
flds.Item(schema & "sendusing") = cdoSendUsingPort
flds.Item(schema & "smtpserver") = "mail.myserver.com" 'your info here
flds.Item(schema & "smtpserverport") = 25
flds.Item(schema & "smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic
flds.Item(schema & "sendusername") = "email@email.com"  'more of your info
flds.Item(schema & "sendpassword") = "password"
flds.Item(schema & "smtpusessl") = False
flds.Update

With imsg
    .To = strTo
    .From = strFrom
    .Subject = strSubj
    .HTMLBody = strBody
    '.body    = strBody
    '.Sender = "Sender"
    '.Organization = "My Company"
    '.ReplyTo = "address@mycompany.com"
    Set .Configuration = iconf
    .Send
End With

Set iconf = Nothing
Set imsg = Nothing
Set flds = Nothing
 End Sub
```

You could either loop through the resultset of your query and call your sendmail function for each email, or write a quick helper function that fetches and concatenates your email fields into a ";" delimited list, and just send the email once with multiple recipients.

Comment: Oh ok, so 'DiscountEmail' needs to be a query? I just found this code elsewhere, and didn't know how to apply it. I guess what I'm asking then is that if I put make this code onLoad, how can I make a query which will suit my needs?

Comment: Yeah, discount email should be a query like `SELECT email FROM Users WHERE dateOfBirth <= date() OR dateOfBirth >= date();`

Comment: OR? Wouldn't it be `AND`? So for example `WHERE dateOfBirth <= date() AND dateOfBirth >= date(); so its so that the DOB is between Today() AND 3daysAway` ?

Comment: Sorry, I may have confused you and myself - you are correct. Your query should be `Select email from Users Where dateOfBirth between dateAdd("d",-3,Date()) AND dateAdd("d",3,Date());`  (untested)  --you may just use "Date" instead of "Date()" as AFAIK, date is a reserved word in acces/vba that just returns the current date.

Comment: Ugh my brain is fried right now. So I just went through about 3 hours work of making it so that I can see when which customers have birthdays within the next month. And looking at this it's as if I don't even need to do that.

Sorry, I'm kind of new to the whole email thing. So how do I actually need to do it so that it sends an email? From what I understand e.g. `Select Email from CustomerInfo Where DOB between dateAdd("d",-3,Date()) AND dateAdd("d",3,Date());` this just selects the email from the query/table, correct? How can I make it so an actual email is sent?

Comment: Ah! Or I can take my query where it shows Birthdays within the next month, change it to birthdays within the next 5 days, then `Select Email from UpcomingBirthday;` and then integrate the send email function into that, so it sends an email to anyone in the query. But how would I go about doing that? Thanks for all your help so far by the way! You've helped me a lot! :)

Comment: Thanks! :) So I'm guessing the second section `With imsg` etc contains the details of who I want to send the email to? `.To =` being their email address, `.From =` being mine? But if that is the case then what are the `'.Sender = "Sender"
    '.Organization = "My Company"
    '.ReplyTo = "address@mycompany.com"`?
Thanks. :)

Comment: @NightSpy2 those fields are commented out, you don't need to worry about them.

Comment: Ok so I changed the details, although I don't have an SMTP server, but I can get one. `.To = UpcomingBirthday.[Email]  .From = "myEmail"  .Subject = "Text"  .HTMLBody = "Text"`  That code should work, am I right? UpcomingBirthday.[Email] is so that it takes the first email address from the query then sends an email to them. Is that correct?

Comment: That should work as a test email, yes. ideally you would use that function like this in an event `Call SendEmail(UpcomingBirthday.[email],"myemail@myemail.com","Birthday Promotion!", "<html>Happy Birthday!<br/> <p> Our records indicate that you're eligible for a birthday promotion.</p></html.")`

Comment: SO that code is under imsg and replaces the .To .From .Subject etc?

Comment: Yup, when you call the function, you pass it in the strTo, strFrom, strSubject, and strMessage variables. That makes it so you dont have to write all that code whenever you want to send an email, you just call the function and give it the to,from,subject,and body.

Comment: Ah ok. So I've put it all in and made it run under a `autoexec` macro, but when it runs it says `Run-Time Error '424' Object Required` Then when I go to debug it highlights this line in yellow: `Call EmailSend(UpcomingBirthday.[Email], "spetsnaz307@hotmail.co.nz", "Birthday Promotion!", "<html>Happy Birthday!<br/> <p> Our records indicate that you're eligible for a birthday promotion.</p></html.")` (My Function is called EmailSend)

Comment: Do you have hotmail's SMTP server settings correct in your function? http://email.about.com/od/accessinghotmail/f/Windows_Live_Hotmail_SMTP_Settings.htm

Comment: Yes my server settings are correct. Hmm. I don't see what 'object' could be required in that line...?

Answer (score 0):

If the essence of your question is about the actual sending of the email message itself, then you may find that `DoCmd.SendObject` may not be the best method. It has several limitations, most significantly (ref: [here](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/email/sendobject.html))

- the message text is limited to 255 characters
- it depends on interaction with an email client application (via MAPI, I assume) so it may not work if there is no mail client configured, or if the mail client is not a Microsoft product

Instead, you might consider sending the messages via CDO. There is a good write-up and some ready-to-use VBA code here:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Email.aspx